# Target newsfeeds of individual Facebook Page followers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, targeting

I have a site where users create posts and customize a feed of content that they're interested in - something like a Twitter list. I would like to be able to push that content (and only that content) to them inside Facebook for possible inclusion in their newsfeed.

If the users are logged into my site using Facebook, **and** they have additionally liked my site's FB Page, is this possible?

I have read about post targeting, but that works at the demographic level. This content feed is per-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not target content on your Facebook page to specific, individual users.

You can target certain demographics or users with certain interests – but not individuals.